# Dependency injection in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have been playing around with dependency injection with javscript but have some questions that I need help with

A simple example is a dialog module I have, used in multiple places on the page it alerts a user with a custom message when a user interacts with a component on the page

```
function Dialog () {

}

Dialog.prototype.show = function () {

}
```

and this may be used in a component, say a search control which validates a user search and if its empty it fires an error dialog. With dependency injection I'm assuming I would write:

```
function searchComponent (dialog) {
   this.dialog = dialog
}

searchComponent.prototype.validateSearch = function () {
    // validate search if invalid create error
    this.dialog.show();
}

var searchDialog = new Dialog();
var search = new searchComponent(searchDialog);
```

However a user may never need the search error dialog, yet I am creating an instance of it just so that I can then pass the dependency through, what if I have 100 individual instances of a dialog on the page do I construct these 100 times, this is unnecessary and expensive in performance.

what I would rather do is lazy load the construction of a dialog to a time when it is needed

```
searchComponent.prototype.validateSearch = function () {
  //validate search if invalid create error
  var dialog = new Dialog();
  dialog.show();
}
```

now I know that this creates disadvantages and one of these is the affects it has on unit testing, what I am keen to understand is whether I have missed something or an alternative method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript functions are first class objects. Instead of passing in a constructed dialog, pass in the dialog constructor function:

```
var search = new SearchComponent(Dialog);
```

Then new it up when you need it:

```
function SearchComponent(Dialog) {
  this.Dialog = Dialog;
}

SearchComponent.prototype.validateSearch = function() {
  var dialog = new this.Dialog();
  dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend @ChrisTavares' great solution, you can use something like this to make dependency injection inside the `Dialog` possible as well:

```
var foo = function () { return new Foo() }; // just an example
var search = new SearchComponent(function() {
    return new Dialog(foo());
});
```

Inside your `SearchComponent`:

```
function SearchComponent(Dialog) {
    this.Dialog = Dialog;
}

SearchComponent.prototype.validateSearch = function () {
    var dialog = new this.Dialog();
    dialog.show();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the previous examples, I've created a simple [jsFiddle](http://goo.gl/NburJ) that utilizes a small library called [Syringe.js](http://syringejs.org) in order to show how dependencies can be injected by pre-binding the `SearchComponent` constructor.

When a `SearchComponent` object is created, the `validator` dependency (a separate component, here taking the place of an actual dialog) is automatically provisioned. This dependency is subsequently used by the `validateSearch` method.

The advantage of doing it this way is that you don't have to have any dependencies in your hand when you create each `SearchComponent` object instance.

In addition, the `validator` dependency can be modified after the`SearchComponent` objects are created, and the behavior of the dependent control(s) can be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a dependency injection library called infect.js. Check it out, might just be what you're looking for. https://github.com/amwmedia/infect.js